# R: fill values in data.frame in parallel mode possible?

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, parallel-processing

I need to run simulations with a variety of options.
My preferred approach would be to create a setup `data.frame` that I fill during the simulation:

```
setup <- expand.grid(
    option_1 = c(1, 2),
    option_2 = c(1, 2),
    value    = NA
)
```

Then,

```
for (idx in 1:nrow(setup)) {
    fit <- fun(a=setup$option_1[idx], b=setup$option_2[idx])
    setup$value[idx] <- fit$value
}
```

Is it possible to parallelize the loop part? I unsuccessfully tried `foreach`. Are there other possibilities?

This is an exemplary function:

```
fun <- function (a, b) {
      list(value = a * b)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this `data.frame`...

```
setup <- expand.grid(
  option_1 = c(1, 2),
  option_2 = c(1, 2),
  value    = NA
)
```

... let's create a copy of setup to compare the reults:

```
setup1 <- setup
```

Then we apply the for loop as you proposed with `fun()`:

```
for (idx in 1:nrow(setup1)) {
  fit <- fun(a = setup1$option_1[idx], b = setup1$option_2[idx])
  setup1$value[idx] <- fit$value
}
```

And this is one solution to use a parallel `foreach` loop:

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

cl <- makeCluster(3, "SOCK") # where 3 is the number of cores used
registerDoSNOW(cl)

setup$value <- foreach(idx = 1:nrow(setup), .combine = c, .inorder = TRUE) %dopar% {
  fit <- fun(setup$option_1[idx], setup$option_2[idx])
  fit$value
}
```

*Note:* it is important to use the option `.inorder=TRUE`. Otherwise the results might be not assigned to the right row of your `setup` data.frame.

Let's check if the two results are identical:

```
identical(setup, setup1)
# [1] TRUE
```

The result looks like this:

```
setup1
#   option_1 option_2 value
# 1        1        1     1
# 2        2        1     2
# 3        1        2     2
# 4        2        2     4
```